# what means by come apostrophe?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, possessives

Any one explain me. Which one is correct time.

**What's time now?**

**What a time now?**

if apostrophe come means it's indicate the position. But if it come in questions pattern's means, what does it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. I think you mean to ask for the time. One might ask

> What's the time?

Here, we use the definite article *the* and notice that *what's* is a contraction of *what is*. The apostrophe does not indicate possession  in this example; it indicates a contraction.

Comment: okay but if i use apostrophe from the subject. for example **The box is her's**

Comment: Sorry, you had to carry the _here_ over. I meant in this example. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Vinothkumar "His", "hers", "ours", "yours", "its" and "theirs" are all possessive words that _never_ use an apostrophe. The word is aready possessive, so no apostrophe is required. This is different from "John's computer" and "my friend's pen" which are not already possessive. Note that "it's" is _not_ possessive - it's a contraction of "it is".